# GMSCameraPosition: convert kilometers to zoom level

Tags: google-maps, gmsmapview

There is a way to convert a distance (in kilometers) into a float zoom level of a GMSCameraPosition?

I have an app where the user specifies a diameter (in kilometers) that he wants to see around the gps checkmark (his position). So, I need to convert that distance (like, 30 km) into a zoom level that fits that distance in kilometers.

I'm very new with Google Maps and didn't find a way to that until now.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For calculating with GPS coordinates have a look [here](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html). (Especially the section "Destination point given distance and bearing from start point").

When you have your coordinates you can use the fitBounds-method of the [Map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map)-object which does exactly what you want.